# how to add up numbers in a listbox in c# on button click

Tags: c#, listbox

hi guys I'm wondering how I can add numbers to a Listbox on button click. for example, I have a button that adds number 20 to Listbox, but when pressed twice the Listbox reads "2020" instead of 40. How can I fix this? this is what I have is `Textbox1.Text = 20.ToString();`

Comment: We cant see your code, and no idea what you are doing. Please consider adding it to the question.. It also might be time to read [ask]

Comment: you need to parse it to integer first, because `"onestring" + "anotherstring" == "onestringanotherstring"`, and listboxes contain strings, not integers. plus, for your next question: please **include the code in question** so we can help without blindly guessing.

Answer (score 1):

`int pos = listBox1.Items.IndexOf("20"); if(pos != -1) listBox1.Items[pos]=Int32.Parse(listBox1.Items[pos])+20).ToString();`
in the first line you locate the item you want to add the new num to with "IndexOf",you get the position of this item in a temp int "pos".
then in the second line you replace this item with himself + the new num using Int.Parse to change the string in the list to an int.

Comment: it would be great if you could add an explanation to your answer - just providing uncommented code might solve the problem, but doesn't teach anything.